# Utilising Powerpoint Template in R quarto document

Tags: r, quarto

I am using Quarto for the first time to generate workplace reports. I need the produced report to be in PowerPoint output, and use our work's common PowerPoint template.

I have named the work PowerPoint template 'template', and saved it on my desktop. When I click 'Home > Layout', the 7 slide titles required are there.

I think I'm doing something wrong wrong in the YAML, that's failing to call the document correctly. My YAML looks like this:

```
title: "My title"
author: "My name"
format:
pptx:
reference-doc: C:\Users\WorkUserName\WorkOneDrive\Desktop\template.pptx
```

Could someone please show me how this should be done? I keep getting error messages like:

Could not find a 0th placeholder of type obj (or nothing)

Many thanks for any help or pointers you can provide!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my error in the end. It was two things:

1. I located my PowerPoint template on my desktop, and solely used the file name for the argument reference-doc. No path required.
2. I also thought I had the correct layouts specified in the PowerPoint file, but didn't. Go to the template's Slide Master through PowerPoint view option, and then select each layout one at a time and rename as required. Quarto's naming requirements seem to vary over time. For the required result go to Quarto's official website and follow their instructions.